# Iframe added extra \ in src tag and height width tag in my php code

Tags: iframe

iframe added autometically extra \ when i added iframe in my form field and map not showing it worrking in localhost but after uploading server its added extra slash please help me. Thank you.

Code of iframe

```
<iframe src=\"https://www.google.com/maps/embed?pb=!1m14!1m8!1m3!1d3204.655372160928!2d-78.06299779999999!3d36.5624217!3m2!1i1024!2i768!4f13.1!3m3!1m2!1s0x89adfb01f721a0fb%3A0xd4727f928bfd3f27!2s287+Winding+Way%2C+Bracey%2C+VA+23919%2C+USA!5e0!3m2!1sen!2sin!4v1426312305027\" width=\"400\" height=\"300\" frameborder=\"0\" style=\"border:0\"></iframe>
```

Comment: <iframe src=\"https://www.google.com/maps/embed?pb=!1m14!1m8!1m3!1d3204.655372160928!2d-78.06299779999999!3d36.5624217!3m2!1i1024!2i768!4f13.1!3m3!1m2!1s0x89adfb01f721a0fb%3A0xd4727f928bfd3f27!2s287+Winding+Way%2C+Bracey%2C+VA+23919%2C+USA!5e0!3m2!1sen!2sin!4v1426312305027\" width=\"400\" height=\"300\" frameborder=\"0\" style=\"border:0\"></iframe>

Answer (score 0):

### Use `stripslashes()` to remove slashes from escaped strings

With PHP:

`$stripped = stripslashes($string);`

Your solution is:

```
$my_string = '<iframe src=\"https://www.google.com/maps/embed?pb=!1m14!1m8!1m3!1d3204.655372160928!2d-78.06299779999999!3d36.5624217!3m2!1i1024!2i768!4f13.1!3m3!1m2!1s0x89adfb01f721a0fb%3A0xd4727f928bfd3f27!2s287+Winding+Way%2C+Bracey%2C+VA+23919%2C+USA!5e0!3m2!1sen!2sin!4v1426312305027\" width=\"400\" height=\"300\" frameborder=\"0\" style=\"border:0\"></iframe>';
echo stripslashes($my_string);
```